# Copy to PRIMARY selection in command

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard

I'm a novice in Lisp, so I feel like I'm missing something very basic here. My intention was to create a function/shortcut to remove all whitespace and newline chars from the selected text and copy the resulting string to the X primary clipboard/selection. For example, when selecting the text:

```
line 1
line 2
```

The function should copy `line1line2` to the clipboard. To be precise, it should be copied to the *primary* selection. I've written the following code for this presumably easy task:

```lisp
(defun copy-no-white-space ()
  (interactive)
  (gui-set-selection
    'PRIMARY
    (replace-regexp-in-string "[\s\n]" "" (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work this way. When I try to paste the modified pattern, it only yields the original region with no modifications and I just can not wrap my head around why: It works when `PRIMARY` is replaced with `CLIPBOARD` (only that I really want to use `PRIMARY`). <s>What confuses me even more is the fact that it works with `PRIMARY` when I remove the regular expression in favor of a fixed string and that it also works when I put it outside of the function.</s> (edit: only when nothing is marked) Why? ;)

Comment: Specify your platform, please. See (emacs) [Primary Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Primary-Selection.html) and [GNUstep Basids](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mac-_002f-GNUstep-Basics.html).

Comment: I clarified this in the post, it is a X window system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [Primary Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Primary-Selection.html) I got a clue for the solution. A simple `deactivate-mark` did the trick for me:

```lisp
(defun copy-no-white-space ()
  (interactive)
  (deactivate-mark)
  (gui-set-selection
    'PRIMARY
    (replace-regexp-in-string "[\s\n]" "" (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

My interpretation is the following: After leaving the `interactive` function, X or Emacs(?) re-evaluates the current selection, to bring the highlighted region to the primary clipboard again. Thinking about it, this probably makes a lot sense for other functions that do not actually want to fiddle with the primary selection, I see that my intention is kind of goofy in this sense.